# Using one-to-many relationship classe/tabl in ArcGIS Desktop for monitoring?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, arcpad, relationship-class

I have a water source feature class in my geodatabase that stores point locations and other non-changing information. I want to monitor these water sources year after year and keep track of the data from year to year (so I don't want to overwrite the previous year's data with the following year's data).

I have a table that has the monitoring categories, and I have created a one:many relationship between the feature class and the table.

How can I best incorporate multiple years of data (through checking the geodatabase in and out of ArcPad on my GPS) into a table(s) related to my feature class?

Answer (score 2):

firs you need to have a [date filed](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000018000000) at you table. Second you should use [COMPOSITE Relationship class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004t00000008000000) — A relationship between dependent objects where the lifetime of one object controls the lifetime of the related object (parent to child). I'm also recommenced on [editor tracing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m600000068000000) Through editor tracking, ArcGIS can automatically record the following information for each feature or table record in a geodatabase dataset:

- The name of the user who created it.
- The date and time it was created.
- The name of the user who edited it.
  *The date and time it was last edited.